# How can I set a default key javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Is there any way to set a `default` key for objects in Javascript like we can do with `switch`?

I want to call that particular key if any other key does not matches. Please refer the below example for the scenario:

**app.component.css**

```
.custom {
  color: aqua;
}

.success {
  color: green;
}

.danger {
  color: red;
}

.wetght {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input class="wetght default {{custom[xyz.abc]}}" [value]="xyz.abc"/><br>
<input class="witght {{custom[xyz.def]}}" [value]="xyz.def"/><br>
<button (click)="abc()">abc</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  xyz = {abc: '', def: ''};
  custom = {
    'PASS': 'success',
    'FAIL': 'danger'
  };

  abc() {
    this.xyz = {abc: 'PASS', def: 'uuu'};
  }
}
```

So this is my scneario. What I want is if the key is not present in the object variable named `custom` then it should look for a default key?

I have already tried using `ng-class` and it's working perfectly but I want to dive into something different.
I have created a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e9bgvh?file=src/app/app.component.ts) also of the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to write a quick directive to bind the class based on another value.

Try the following

**status.directive.ts**

```js
import {
  Directive,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  Renderer2,
  ElementRef,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[status]"
})
export class StatusDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() mapping: { [state: string]: string };
  @Input() state: string;
  @Input() default: string = "default";

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges) {
    if (!!this.state) {
      this.renderer.addClass(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement,
        !!this.mapping[this.state] ? this.mapping[this.state] : this.default
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<input status [mapping]="custom" [state]="xyz.abc" class="wetght" [value]="xyz.abc"/><br>
<input status [mapping]="custom" [state]="xyz.def" class="wetght" [value]="xyz.def"/><br>
<button (click)="abc()">abc</button>
```

**app.component.css**

```css
.custom {
  color: aqua;
}

.default {
  color: blue;
}

.success {
  color: green;
}

.danger {
  color: red;
}

.wetght {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsqznv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: thanks. I have marked this answer approved as this is more precise & clear though it is long

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
[class.default]="!custom[xyz.abc]"
```

Comment: I want it in 1 go rather than keep this here and that there. If that can be done it will be great

Comment: Then `ngClass` is what your're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method in your `AppComponent` to compute the target classname

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  getOrDefault(key: string): string {
    return this.custom[key] || 'default';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input ngClass="['wetght', getOrDefault(xyz.abc)]" [value]="xyz.abc"/><br>
<input ngClass="['wetght', getOrDefault(xyz.def)]" [value]="xyz.def"/><br>
```